# Jekyll different permalinks for posts than other pages

Tags: jekyll, permalinks, github-pages

I am using `permalink: pretty` for all of my site (static pages).

However for blog posts, I would like to use `permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/`.

How do I set two different permalink styles?

Comment: you could override the general permalink style in the front matter of your blog posts

Answer (score 1):

My working solution, in _config.yml:

```
permalink: pretty
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      category: blog
```

Since the `pretty` settings prepends the category to the path, I set that all posts should have a category of `blog`.